# Verificar se CONSTANT existe na Package

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

tenho uma Package:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE LETRAS AS
  possuiA     CONSTANT BOOLEAN NOT NULL := TRUE;
  possuiB    CONSTANT BOOLEAN NOT NULL := TRUE;
  possuiC    CONSTANT BOOLEAN NOT NULL := TRUE;
  possuiD     CONSTANT BOOLEAN NOT NULL := FALSE;
  possuiE    CONSTANT BOOLEAN NOT NULL := FALSE;
  possuiF     CONSTANT BOOLEAN NOT NULL := FALSE;
 END db1integra;
```

E porém gostaria de verificar em um select se existe a CONSTANT possuiG, 
e se caso existir então executo uma ação se for TRUE se for FALSE não executo.

pode ser feita a verificação dessa forma:
(o script abaixo não funciona, não posso fazer validação
de uma constant que não existe)

```
DECLARE
  vsql VARCHAR(1000);
BEGIN
  IF letras.possuig THEN
    vsql :=  'UPDATE EMPLOYEE
              SET JOB = DEFAULT
              WHERE EMPNO = ''000290''';
  ELSE
    vsql :=  'UPDATE EMPLOYEE
              SET JOB = DEFAULT
              WHERE EMPNO = ''000210''';
  END IF;
END;
```

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recompile sua package com o parâmetro [`PLSCOPE_SETTINGS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams194.htm#REFRN10271) setado para `IDENTIFIERS:ALL` (para mais informações veja [Using PL/Scope](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_plscope.htm#ADFNS396)).

```
ALTER SESSION SET PLSCOPE_SETTINGS='IDENTIFIERS:ALL'/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE letras AS 
  possuiA     CONSTANT BOOLEAN NOT NULL := TRUE;
  possuiB    CONSTANT BOOLEAN NOT NULL := TRUE;
  possuiC    CONSTANT BOOLEAN NOT NULL := TRUE;
  possuiD     CONSTANT BOOLEAN NOT NULL := FALSE;
  possuiE    CONSTANT BOOLEAN NOT NULL := FALSE;
  possuiF     CONSTANT BOOLEAN NOT NULL := FALSE;
END letras; 
/
```

Com isso você poderá usar as views `USER_IDENTIFIERS` e `ALL_IDENTIFIERS` para verificar se uma constante foi declarada.

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER_IDENTIFIERS
WHERE 
  NAME = 'POSSUIF'
  AND TYPE = 'CONSTANT'
  AND USAGE = 'DECLARATION'
  AND OBJECT_NAME = 'LETRAS'
  AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE';
```

---

[**Exemplo funcional no SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d334c/1)

Comment: Impressão minha ou somente funciona no 11g? Existe alguma forma de fazer isso no 10g

Comment: Parece que o [PLScope](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/whatsnew.htm#CHDJFGEB) só entrou na versão 11g mesmo. Não conheço nenhuma maneira de fazer isso no 10g.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado vou ver o que faço aqui